# Dynamic animation scrolling speed in css

Tags: html, css, performance, animation, scroll

i have animation that scrolls list in horizontal direction. When more and more elements are added to the list it starts to scroll faster.
I need to make the scroll speed the same for any list length.

my css

```
   .horizontal.scroll .list_rail {
    animation: scrollX 15s infinite linear
  }
```

i assume it should be something like

```
.horizontal.scroll .list_rail {
    animation: scrollX calc(15s + $('ul#list li').length) infinite linear
  }
```

Comment: as far as I know, this CSS does not work as well. You can try it with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

maybe use `<marquee>` tag .

```
 <marquee direction=right>
  <ul id="addList">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
</marquee>

<button onClick="add()">ADD li</button>
```

css

```
li{
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 3px;
}

ul{
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
  flex-direction:row-reverse; 
}
```

script

```
function add(){
  var ul = document.getElementById('addList');
  var li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = 'other text';
  ul.appendChild(li)
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/volkancode/pen/BObQJL?editors=0010)

Comment: isn't marquee obsolete? This would make it not a good long term solution...
Allthrough i will try out the js approach thx